# remove JS and CSS file in ie8 and older

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ive got this `<head>`:

```
<head>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/animated/animate.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
 <script type='text/javascript' src='/animated/animated.js'></script>
</head>
```

and I need to have these two files disabled in IE8 and lower.

Is there any way how to do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer and it works perfectly, check it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **conditional comments**. In this case you can use -

```
<head>
    <!--[if gt IE 8]> <!-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/animated/animate.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/animated/animated.js'></script>
    <!-- <![endif]-->
</head>
```

**Note that:** `gt` means *'greater than'* while `gte` means *'greater than or equal'*.

Learn more about conditional comments from **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx)**